# Get all combinations of infinite nested lists

Tags: python, combinations

I need to be able to get all the combinations from any number of dimensions of an array. Basically to "flatten" it out into all the possible combinations.

I've been trying to use this:

```py
def enum_sub(arr):
    if len(arr) == 0:
        return [[]]
    if isinstance(arr[0], list):
        return [[i] + j for i in arr[0] for j in enum_sub(arr[1:])]
    return [[arr[0]] + j for j in enum_sub(arr[1:])]
```

But it is only able to calculate the probabilities up to a depth of 2.

E.g this works as intended:

```py
print(enum_sub(['a', 'b', 'c', ['d', 'e']]))
# [['a', 'b', 'c', 'd'], ['a', 'b', 'c', 'e']]
```

and this:

```py
print(enum_sub(['a', 'b', 'c', ['d', 'e'], ['f', 'g']]))
# [['a', 'b', 'c', 'd', 'f'], ['a', 'b', 'c', 'd', 'g'], ['a', 'b', 'c', 'e', 'f'], ['a', 'b', 'c', 'e', 'g']]
```

Whereas this isn't:

```py
print(enum_sub(['a', 'b', 'c', ['d', 'e'], ['f', ['g', 'h']]]))
# [['a', 'b', 'c', 'd', 'f'], ['a', 'b', 'c', 'd', ['g', 'h']], ['a', 'b', 'c', 'e', 'f'], ['a', 'b', 'c', 'e', ['g', 'h']]]
# expected to get [['a', 'b', 'c', 'd', 'f', 'g'], ['a', 'b', 'c', 'd', 'f', 'h'], ['a', 'b', 'c', 'e', 'f', 'g'], ['a', 'b', 'c', 'e', 'f', 'h']]
```

Comment: It's not clear why you have more than one layer of nesting at all - given your expected output, it looks like all "intermediate" layers are superfluous. Is there any case where the expected output would be different if you removed all "intermediate" layers of nesting?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I tried to understand the logic behind your request but i felt the combination you had in mind did not make much sense especially with regards to the multiple combination in double / triple nested lists.

My logic was that the program would iterate thru the list, and if the element in the list was a list, there would be n number of combinations, with n being the length of the nested list.

Assuming a simple list of

```
l1 = ['a','b',['d','e']]
```

Combination 1: `[l1[0],l1[1],l1[2][0]]`
Combination 2: `[l1[0],l1[1],l1[2][1]]`

Your code of:

```
print(enum_sub(['a', 'b', 'c', ['d', 'e'], ['f', ['g', 'h']]]))
```

should yield an output which iterates thru the index.
it should look like the code below:

```
[['a', 'b', 'c', 'd', 'f'], ['a', 'b', 'c', 'e', 'f'], ['a', 'b', 'c', 'd', 'g'], ['a', 'b', 'c', 'e', 'g'], ['a', 'b', 'c', 'd', 'h'], ['a', 'b', 'c', 'e', 'h']]
```

You can see that the different combinations happen due to the nested list and based on the index in an ascending manner.

You can try studying the code below to see how it works out.

```
def flatten_list(nested_list):
    if not isinstance(nested_list, list):
        return [[nested_list]]

    stack = [nested_list]
    combinations = []

    while stack:
        current = stack.pop()
        if isinstance(current, list):
            stack.extend(current[::-1])  # Reverse the order to maintain the desired order of combinations
        else:
            combinations.append([current])

    return combinations


def generate_combinations(nested_list):
    total_list = [[]]

    for item in nested_list:
        if isinstance(item, list):
            current_list = total_list.copy()
            combinations = flatten_list(item)
            total_list = []
            for comb in combinations:
                for lst in current_list:
                    total_list.append(lst + comb)
        else:
            for lst in total_list:
                lst.append(item)

    return total_list


nested_list = [1, [2, [3, 4], 5], 6]
combinations = generate_combinations(nested_list)
print(combinations)

nested_list1 = [1, [2, [3, 4], 5], [7,8]]
combinations1 = generate_combinations(nested_list1)
print(combinations1)

nested_list2 = ['a', 'b', 'c', ['d', 'e'], ['f', ['g', 'h']]]
combinations2 = generate_combinations(nested_list2)
print(combinations2)
```

Answer (score 0):

The main problem here is that you have two different logics when dealing with a sub-list in an input list--one when the sub-list contains only non-list items, and another when the sub-list contains other list items. In the former case you would perform a Cartesian product with individual items in that sub-list. In the latter case make a recursive call with the sub-list and then perform a Cartesian product with the returning list of sub-lists and join each of those sub-lists with the current list:

```
def enum_sub(arr):
    output = [[]]
    for i in reversed(arr):
        if not isinstance(i, list):
            output = [[i] + lst for lst in output]
        elif any(isinstance(j, list) for j in i):
            output = [j + lst for j in enum_sub(i) for lst in output]
        else:
            output = [[j] + lst for j in i for lst in output]
    return output
```

so that:

```
enum_sub(['a', 'b', 'c', ['d', 'e'], ['f', ['g', 'h']]])
```

returns:

```
[['a', 'b', 'c', 'd', 'f', 'g'], ['a', 'b', 'c', 'd', 'f', 'h'], ['a', 'b', 'c', 'e', 'f', 'g'], ['a', 'b', 'c', 'e', 'f', 'h']]
```

Demo: https://replit.com/@blhsing/OddballEmotionalProperty

Answer (score 0):

You can also use `itertools.product` to produce a Cartesian product:

```
from itertools import product, chain

def enum_sub(arr):
    return [
        list(chain.from_iterable(p))
        for p in product(
            *(
                [[i]] if not isinstance(i, list)
                else enum_sub(i) if any(isinstance(j, list) for j in i)
                else i
                for i in arr
            )
        )
    ]
```

so that:

```
enum_sub(['a', 'b', 'c', ['d', 'e'], ['f', ['g', 'h']]])
```

returns:

```
[['a', 'b', 'c', 'd', 'f', 'g'], ['a', 'b', 'c', 'd', 'f', 'h'], ['a', 'b', 'c', 'e', 'f', 'g'], ['a', 'b', 'c', 'e', 'f', 'h']]
```

Demo: https://replit.com/@blhsing/PointlessGloomyUsernames